# checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

There is two choices; english or nonenglish. When you don't choose any of them or chose both of them, it is supposed to give error but it doesn't give. Could you please help?Thank you. ps: Even though I make it one checkbox for terms and conditions, alert doesn't work.

JavaScript

```
function onFormSubmit(form_element) {

        if (form_element.click.checked == false)
                {
                alert("Please check language");
                return false;
                }
    return true;
}

HTML

<form onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this)">
        Language: <input type="checkbox" name="click" value="english">english
</form>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a radio input instead? That way only one can be chosen, and the browser should default to checking one by default.

Comment: Yes I know it is easier but it is supposed to be checkbox. :(

Comment: "Supposed to be" why? For this use-case it really *should* be radio input.

Comment: Try not to use `click` as its a keyword on JS.

Comment: In this scenario, radio button should be the choice, not a checkbox. The reason why radio buttons and checkboxes are separated is because of cases like this, where a default option has to be selected, and only one option can be selected at once. You can of course, style your radio button in anyway you desire (even mimic the look of a checkbox, but that would be counterintuitive, no?)

Answer (score 1):

Condition should be...

```
if ((form_element.click_1.checked == true && form_element.click_2.checked == true) || (form_element.click_1.checked == false && form_element.click_2.checked == false))
```

**Edit**

This is what I used.

```
<script>
function onFormSubmit(form_element) {

        if ((form_element.click_1.checked == true && form_element.click_2.checked == true) || (form_element.click_1.checked == false && form_element.click_2.checked == false))
                {
                alert("Please check language");
                return false;
                }
    return true;
}
</script>


<form onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this)">
        Language: <input type="checkbox" name="click_1" value="english">english
                  <input type="checkbox" name="click_2" value="non english">non english</p>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. When I choose both or none of them, it still doesn't give any error.

Comment: When I used this condition, it did show me the alert message for both these conditions...

Comment: it doesnt show me any alert. How can I write it any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "onFormSubmit(this)" -- 'this' will not refer to the form when the event is called. If you look up the form from the document instead it will work fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        if (!form.language.checked) {
                alert("Please check language");
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        Language: <input type="checkbox" name="language">English</input><br />
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want check boxes? Radio buttons would be better as only one can be selected at a time.

Comment: I changed it as terms of conditions and I need checkbox

Comment: The reason your function doesn't work is because you're calling it wrong. If you can't change the function change the form:

<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(document.getElementById('myForm'))">...

Comment: Edited to show a working example. Tested in chrome and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this)">
        Language: <input type="checkbox" name="click_1" value="english">english
                  <input type="checkbox" name="click_2" value="non english">non english</p>
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onFormSubmit(form_element) {
  if ((form_element.click_1.checked == true && form_element.click_2.checked == true)) {
      alert("Please check only one choice!");
      return false;
  } else if ((form_element.click_1.checked == false && form_element.click_2.checked == false)) {
      alert("Please check your choice!");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/3AWUp/

Answer (score 0):

I added a submit button to your HTML and ids on each element

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
        Language: <input id="english" type="checkbox" name="click_1" value="english">english
                  <input id="nonEnglish" type="checkbox" name="click_2" value="non english">non english</p>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I attach a function to the onsubmit event the performs validation.
Javascript

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit =
function () {
        if ((document.getElementById("english").checked == false && document.getElementById("nonEnglish").checked == false) || (document.getElementById("english").checked == true && document.getElementById("nonEnglish").checked == true))
                {
                alert("Please check language");
                return false;
                }
    return true;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j3J4E/

Comment: Thank you but I have to use the original function.